# How to re-enable my once disabled button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've searched the questions here about 'how to enable my disabled button' but the one with the 'removeAttribute' simply does not work, don't know why. 
I have this problem - once I reach 0 with my decrementing button it goes disabled so the user can't decrement to negative number but the problem is when I use the increment button the decrement one stays disabled, why ? I will be very greatfull if you guys tell me another way to solve this task. The point is I am now allowed to decrement below 0.
Here are my HTML and JS:

```js
var value = 1;
var plus = document.getElementById('plus');
var minus = document.getElementById('minus');


function add() {
  value++;
  document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = value;
}

function take() {
  value--;
  document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = value;
  if (value == 0) {
    minus.disabled = true;
  } else {
    minus.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="ADD" id="plus" onclick="add();">
<input type="button" value="TAKE" id="minus" onclick="take();">
<span id="num">1</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you do not run the logic when you click on the add button. You only do it on the minus button.

I would break it out into it own function

```js
var value = 1;
var plus = document.getElementById('plus');
var minus = document.getElementById('minus');


function add() {
  value++;
  document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = value;
  setBtnStates();
}

function take() {
  value--;
  document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = value;
  setBtnStates();
}

function setBtnStates() {
  if (value == 0) {
    minus.disabled = true;
  } else {
    minus.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="ADD" id="plus" onclick="add();">
<input type="button" value="TAKE" id="minus" onclick="take();">
<span id="num">1</span>
```

The statement can be simplified to

```
function setBtnStates() {
    minus.disabled = value == 0;
}
```